# framed package change math?

Tags: math-operators, framed

This code :

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}
bla bla bla $\cap_{i\in I} X_i.$
\end{document}
```

produces : 
[image: Symbol without framed package]

and the same code with the line `\usepackage{framed}` uncommented produces :

[image: Symbol with framed package]

!!? How can this be possible ? I had a look at the framed.sty file and there is nothing like a "\cap" redefinition... ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in my system (TeX Live2014). Which LaTeX distribution do you use?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001)

Comment: Miktex 2.9 on win 7.
Maybe just a dvi problem ? I always use YAP. I'm going to see the PDF...

Comment: No, same result with pdflatex and the intern pdf viewer of TexStudio.

Comment: Hum... without being "trolly", is TexLive "better" than Miktex in the sense that you have less problems using packages and compatibility ? (I have always used Miktex, so I don't know anything about other distribution...)

Comment: i can't reproduce this with tex live 2012, and have checked `framed.sty` to make sure the version used is still the same on ctan.  (it is.)

Comment: I tested this in two files there is no difference. Miktex2.9 acrobat11

Comment: The `framed.sty` in the standard distribution will not change the fonts. please add  `\listfiles` to your example, uncomment the `framed` line and then if it still changes the font add the full log to your question, so we can see what it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `framed` the responsible for this change in the math symbols, but `MnSymbol`.

Here's the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}
bla bla bla $\cap_{i\in I} X_i.$
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Don't* trust in advice (even if it's from this site) telling you to use the package just because it provides some symbol you need, because this package changes ***all*** math symbols to shapes that are thought to blend with the Minion font and are definitely out of place with Computer Modern (see the ugly `\in`).

Look at [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386) for importing just the symbols you need.

By the way, the correct way to input that formula is

```
$\bigcap_{i\in I}X_{i}$.
```

Note `\bigcap` and the full stop outside the formula.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't understand. Why is the MnSymbol involved in my example, because I don't use it via \usepackage ? The change arises when I put \usepackage{framed}. There are no other package imported in my example...

And by the way, in effect other symbols are affected... :(

Comment: @Carrérond No, it's really impossible that just loading `framed` causes the problem, unless you have a bogus `framed.sty` somewhere on your system.

Comment: @Carrérond Can you look in the `log` file for the path to `framed.sty`? You should find something like `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty
Package: framed 2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks` Search for `framed.sty`.

Comment: You're right : in fact, framed uses the mnsymbol package (line 110 of framed.sty is \usepackage{mnsymbol}) !!
Now I understand... 
I'm going to make tries (comment the line...) to see what happens :-). Otherwise, I don't know what to do...

Comment: @Carrérond As I said, you have a bogus copy of `framed.sty`; the CTAN one doesn't load `MnSymbol`.

Comment: Yes, understood. I didn't know there would exist many different versions of a package... I don't remember where I picked up my version ?
Thanks for the help :).